# Need help to output data from xml

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I look that have more posts of the subject, but i no find my problem.
Please Help.

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">1/26/2022 2:02:34 PM;עומר;-100;3;-100</string>
```

I need to output values betwen ';'

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please see how to extract the values below:

```
[xml]$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">1/26/2022 2:02:34 PM;עומר;-100;3;-100</string>'

$xml.string.'#text' -split ";"
```

This will output:

```
1/26/2022 2:02:34 PM
עומר
-100
3
-100
```